# Pad or truncate string based on fixed length

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Currently have code that looks something like;

```
print '{: <5}'.format('test')
```

This will pad my string with `' '` if it is less than 5 characters. If the string is more than 5 characters, I'd need the string to be truncated.

Without explicitly checking the length of my string before formatting it, is there a better way to pad if less than fixed length or truncate if greater than fixed length?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `5.5` to [combine truncating and padding](https://pyformat.info/#string_trunc_pad) so that the output will always be of length of five:

```
'{:5.5}'.format('testsdf')
# 'tests'

'{:5.5}'.format('test')
# 'test '
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `str.ljust` and slice the string:

```
>>> 'testsdf'.ljust(5)[:5]
'tests'
>>> 'test'.ljust(5)[:5]
'test '
```